# solr-6.5.1 org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: can not sort on a PointField without doc values: metadata_modified

Tags: indexing, solr, runtime-error, runtimeexception, ckan

I am a bit stuck with error **org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: can not sort on a PointField without doc values: metadata_modified**.

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: can not sort on a PointField without doc values: metadata_modified
    at org.apache.solr.schema.SchemaField.checkSortability(SchemaField.java:174)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.DatePointField.getSortField(DatePointField.java:133)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.SchemaField.getSortField(SchemaField.java:150)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SortSpecParsing.parseSortSpecImpl(SortSpecParsing.java:202)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SortSpecParsing.parseSortSpec(SortSpecParsing.java:60)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getSortSpec(QParser.java:285)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:187)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:269)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2440)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:723)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:529)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:347)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

the error seems to be coming from the **schema.xml**, on this line here  `<field name="metadata_modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>` , I have tried adding **docValues = "true"** as solr documentation suggests but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea on how this should be fixed ?

Comment: If you change the definition, you'll have to reindex your content; just adding the `docValues="true"` won't change anything by itself.

Comment: Any hint on how I can do that ?

Comment: Reindexing? Clean out the index and submit the documents to Solr again.

Comment: Well, I tried to rebuild the index as CKAN recommends here **ckan -c /etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini search-index rebuild**, but nothing seems to work!

Comment: You have to also make sure that everything in the index has been removed first, so that the fields are redefined when reindexing. Delete the `data` directories first.

Comment: Well, I tried that and didn't work either, so I decided to upgrade from solr-6.5.1 to solr-8.9.0, some changes were made starting from solr- >= 7.0, worked on that and everything work. Thanks @MatsLindh for your help.